# Mystery mtb frame

Tags: identify-this-bike

I have a cannondale but not really. Serial number KS782023. Seatpost is 26.6 or 26.8, has a lower u brake like a 1988 Rocky Mountain hammer or trek 8000 but it’s neither. Anyone know what this is? It’s around 87-88, the head tube angle is like a road bike.

Comment: Welcome to the site! It would be difficult to identify without pictures, post a few clear pictures of the frame highlighting anything you think is unique. Someone may then be able to identify it.

Comment: Not an answer but you can download the Cannondale vintage catalogues from here https://vintagecannondale.com/catalog/ if you have a rough idea of year it should be in the relevant catalogue even if the parts have been changed the frame should be the same

Comment: https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Answer (score 3):

Cannondale is one of the few manufacturers with documented serial number meanings.

Downside, there's 6 different serial number schemes from 1983 to current.

And your number doesn't match any of them, but 1999 comes closest with: [image: from https://vintagecannondale.com/info/serial_numbers/]

```
E=1993, F=1994, G=1995, H=1996, I=1997, J=1998, K=1999

A=January, B=February, C=March, D=April, E=May, F=June, G=July,
H=August, I=September, J=October, K=November, L=December
```

But there is no month code for "S"

More info at https://vintagecannondale.com/info/serial_numbers/

Thing is, this info tells you very little, and nothing useful outside of an original-spec rebuild.